# Should hasOwnProperty still be used with for..in statements

Tags: javascript

There are a lot of blogs saying that a `hasOwnProperty` check should be used whenever the `for..in` loop is used, but I don't understand why that's the case. Both with and without the check we get the same results.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mothi_gautham/gFmXM/).

Comment: check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/gFmXM/1/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're creating a basic object with `{}`, or getting it from JSON using `JSON.parse`, then `hasOwnProperty` is globally useless.

But if you're extending a "class" (using *prototype*), then it helps you to know if you're accessing your "own properties" (direct properties, including direct functions).

Note that a basic object has at least one (not direct) property, that you may discover with `console.log({});` or `console.log({}.toString)` but [it's not enumerable and not seen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) in a `for... in` loop :

> A for...in loop does not iterate over non–enumerable properties.
> Objects created from built–in constructors like Array and Object have
> inherited non–enumerable properties from Object.prototype and
> String.prototype that are not enumerable, such as String's indexOf
> method or Object's toString method. The loop will iterate over all
> enumerable properties of the object or that it inherits from its
> constructor's prototype (including any which overwrite built-in
> properties).

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is not useless and necessary when you don't have full control over the code in your page. Say someone modifies `Object.prototype` as in Cristoph's answer.. even with a simple object you will get unpredictable results without `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: I'd say that messing code which you don't have full control is a different category from *creating a basic object with {}, or getting it from JSON*

Answer (score 13):

Without `hasOwnProperty` you don't know whether the property is a native property of your object or inherited from it's prototype.

**[Your modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/gFmXM/2/)**

```
var obj1 = {a:"10",b:"20"};

Object.prototype.c = "prototype:30";

var i;
for(i in obj1) {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML += obj1[i]+" ";
}
// result 10 20 prototype:30

for(i in obj1) {
    if(obj1.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML += obj1[i] +" ";
    }          
}
// result 10 20
​
```

In this case `obj1` inherits the property `c` from it's Prototype `Object` and you would erroneously list it in your first loop.

Answer (score 1):

Often you will get the same result with or without `hasOwnProperty`, but the latter ignores properties that are inherited rather than living directly on the object in question.

Consider this basic inheritance system. Dogs inherit from the master Animal class.

```
function Animal(params) { this.is_animal = true; }
function Dog(params) { for (var i in params) this[i] = params[i]; }
Dog.prototype = new Animal();
var fido = new Dog({name: 'Fido'});
```

If we peer into `fido`, `hasOwnProperty` helps us ascertain which are its own properties (name) and which are inherited.

```
for (var i in fido) if (fido.hasOwnProperty(i)) alert(i+' = '+fido[i]);
```

...alerts `name=Fido` but not `is_animal=true`.

Answer (score 1):

this is why we need hasOwnProperty() method in for..in statement : this is not useless, this is very important to make your code safe and to make it always do right thing.because some libraries or some dependencies could touch Object.prototype on your program context in anytime, Without hasOwnProperty check, your for...in statement  might be iterating unexpected keys. So you need to make your for...in statement safe using hasOwnProperty().

```js
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
Object.prototype.haha = 3;
for (var k in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)){
  console.log(k); // prints a, b
  }
}   

var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};

Object.prototype.haha = 3;

for (var k in obj) {
  console.log(k); // prints a, b, haha
}
```