# How to loop thru this kind of array and get the label or name of each element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array: I don't know what kind of array this is.

```
var catz ={
cafe:{class:'orange',color:'E6674A',font:'000'},
bar:{class:'orange',color:'E6674A',font:'000'},
restaurant:{class:'green',color:'a8e52f',font:'000'}
};
```

and I'm trying to alert the category: Ex. it should alert: cafe, then bar, and then restaurant.

```
for (var j = 0;j < 3;j++){
    alert (catz[j]);
}
```

then I'd like to also get the color

it works with this array, but I'm using the other array.

```
var catz = ["cafe", "bar", "restaurant"];
```

Thanks

Comment: It's called an object. Actually what you have is an object full of objects.

Comment: If you'd read a basic JavaScript tutorial, you'd learn about the `for-in` statements used for objects.

Comment: ...and IMO, don't use `.hasOwnProperty()` as the answers below are showing. Only use it when you know you need it.

Comment: I dont understand why people are getting obsessed of `hasOwnProperty()`, they are trying to make it **fancy**, even if this  is not required.

Comment: As if JS wasn't fancy enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var catz ={
    cafe:{class:'orange',color:'E6674A',font:'000'},
    bar:{class:'orange',color:'E6674A',font:'000'},
    restaurant:{class:'green',color:'a8e52f',font:'000'}
};

for(var key in catz){
    alert(key + " : " + catz[key].color);
}
```

this will alert `cafe : E6674A`, and so on...

http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/qVp5u/

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over properties of an object using a for in loop.

```
for (var key in catz) {
    if (catz.hasOwnProperty(key))
        console.log(key, catz[key]);
}
```

Console output:

```
cafe Object {class: "orange", color: "E6674A", font: "000"}
bar Object {class: "orange", color: "E6674A", font: "000"}
restaurant Object {class: "green", color: "a8e52f", font: "000"}
```

Answer (score 2):

walk through the object and retrieve the keys

```
for (category in catz) {
   if (catz.hasOwnProperty(category)) {
      console.log(category)
   }
}
```

Note: in your specific example the `if` statement could not be really necessary (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314053/1098851) - comment included - for further information)