# Using Objects in For Of Loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, iterable

Why isn't is possible to use objects in for of loops? Or is this a browser bug? This code doesn't work in Chrome 42, saying undefined is not a function:

```
test = { first: "one"}

for(var item of test) {
  console.log(item)
}
```

Comment: Is test an array or object?

Comment: @KickButtowski, can't you see? It is definitely an object.

Comment: for (let key of Object.keys(test)) { ... }

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I made objects iterable with this code:

```
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
 for(let key of Object.keys(this)) {
  yield([ key, this[key] ])
} }
```

Usage:

```
for(let [ key, value ] of {}) { }
```

Alternativly:

```
for(let [ key, value ] of Object.entries({})) { }
```

Comment: No idea why this is the accepted solution. Modifying the prototype unless its a polyfill is always a terrible idea.

Comment: @user1703761 It is the accepted solution because it works. Please explain what problems this will cause if it is so terrible.

Comment: There are all sorts of issues, mainly forward compatibility ones. One example is that Array.prototype.includes which was previously names contains but Moo Tools extended the prototype and the implementation was incompatible, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1075059

Also look up the Prototype library desaster ;)

Comment: I believe that this will not have forward compatibility issues because if an iterator was added to objects this would overwrite it and if an iterator was added to an object subtype it would use the subtype iterator.

Comment: Hey guys, modifying the prototype is a bad idea!!! Let's shame the OP for actually giving an answer to the question!

Comment: Downvoted because of the call to `Object.keys`. One of the nice things about generators is that they can be chained together lazily. The call to `Object.keys` ruins the laziness by eagerly creating a new array of the keys. A better solution would be to use [`for in` with a `hasOwnProperty` check or `propertyIsEnumerable` check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Iterating_over_own_properties_only) then yielding

Comment: @RicoKahler Would it really have a performance impact? And in my testing it seems like for in loops also work with the keys at the time the loop is entered.

Comment: @DanielHerr hmm... if `for in` also eagerly grabs the keys then there's no difference. it's a small thing though, the performance difference is probably negligible.

Comment: @RicoKahler But the native array and map iterators do include keys added later, so I should probably solve that for consistency.

Comment: I did [a performance test](https://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-for-in-for-object-generators) and it seems like `for in` is faster. Can you confirm on your browser?

Comment: Oh oops, I never published that test. View it here. https://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-for-in-for-object-generators/1

Comment: dangerous, scurry

Comment: @webdevinci What?

Comment: @DanielHerr Overriding the Object prototype... Very cool & smart solution, but the bigger the project, the bigger the risk that comes in to play.

Comment: @webdevinci What exactly is the risk? Can you give me a possible example?

Comment: @DanielHerr: It's deemed bad practice in enterprise environments to override native prototypes. Without googling a douglas crawford quote, I'd say the main danger of doing this in general is when ECMA adds/removes props to the prototype which you have now overwritten; could cause a clash, or unexpected behavior. Maintainability-wise, having a larger team, you'll have one person using 'for of' loops on objects and the rest using 'for in', and those whom aren't aware of the shim will auto-think 'they are using for of, this can't be an object', & end up confused or wasting time finding the cause

Comment: @DanielHerr We don't modify prototypes for very good reason. Because this breaks encapsulation and provides global changes in code behaviour. Sometimes it may be a matter of principle, but in this case the pitfall is obvious - if (when) objects will become iterable, reassigned `Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` can break any other spec-compiant piece of code. If you need to customize built-in class behaviour, subclass it, it's always as simple as that. E.g. [same thing but done right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35819888/3731501).

Comment: I think OP here is just to show...it's doable (yet not recommended)

Answer (score 82):

The [for..of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) only supports iterable objects like arrays, not objects.

To iterate over the values of an object, use:

```
for (var key in test) {
    var item = test[key];
}
```

Comment: Neither ES5 nor ES6 define `Object.values`.

Comment: Yup, that's what I already use. But what makes an object "iterable"?

Comment: @DanielHerr Having an `.iterable` member function, which is where the error comes from when you try to use it on an object (which doesn't have it). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Comment: I mean, why don't objects have that? What would be the problem with natively adding it?

Comment: @DanielHerr I don't have the answer to that, you'll have to ask the people who design the language.

Comment: @DanielHerr If the Object "base class" were iterable, so would any Function/Date/etc "subclass" amongst other complications. See https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es6-iteration-over-object-values#content-5 for a more thorough/accurate discussion of your question though.

Comment: With this for..in solution, don't you still technically have to do a check for `if (test.hasOwnProperty(key)){ ... }`? Or is that not needed?

Comment: @tennisgent *If you're creating a basic object with `{}`, or getting it from json using `JSON.Parse`, `hasOwnProperty` is globally useless. But…*: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11314053/1250044

Comment: @DanielHerr The difference between iterable (e.g. arrays) and non-iterable (native object) collections is that the iterable ones have a solid definition on the order by which their elements should be iterated. Objects are just lookups, and the spec states that you should never rely on the order of keys or values (e.g. when using a for-in loop), hence why they are not considered "iterable".

Answer (score 64):

You can use this syntax:

```js
const myObject = {
  first: "one",
  second: "two",
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myObject)) {
  console.log(key, value);  // first one, second two
}
```

However, [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) <del>has poor support right now</del> does not work in IE <del>or iOS Safari</del>. You'll <del>probably</del> might need a polyfill. See https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_entries for the latest scoop.

See also `Object.keys` to iterate just the keys, or `Object.values` for just the values.

Answer (score 36):

If you are storing data in a key-value store, [**please use `Map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which is explicitly designed for this purpose.

If you have to use an object though, ES2017 (ES8) allows you to use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
const foo = { a: 'foo', z: 'bar', m: 'baz' };
for (let value of Object.values(foo)) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

If that isn't supported yet, use a polyfill: [Alternative version for `Object.values()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42830257/2074608)

And finally if you're supporting an older environment that don't support this syntax, you'll have to resort to using `forEach` and `Object.keys`:

```
var obj = { a: 'foo', z: 'bar', m: 'baz' };
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (prop) {
    var value = obj[prop];
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: couldn't Object prototype be extended to support this?

Comment: @SonicSoul: technically yes, but it's generally not advised to extend the Object prototype as (pretty much) everything inherits from it.

Comment: `Object.entries` can by polyfilled without touching the prototype.

Comment: Why use maps instead of objects?

Comment: Is there any advantage to using these complex examples over a simple `for-in`?

Answer (score 18):

> Iterator, Iterable and for..of loop in ECMAScript 2015/ ES6

```
let tempArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

for(element of tempArray) {
  console.log(element);
}

// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
```

But if we do

```
let tempObj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

for(element of tempObj) {
   console.log(element);
}
// error
```

We get error because **for..of** loop works only on **Iterables**, that is, the object which has an **@@iterator** that adheres to **Iterator protocol**, meaning it must have an object with a **next** method. The next method takes no arguments and it should return an object with these two properties.

**done**: signals that the sequence has ended when true, and false means there may be more values
**value**: this is the current item in the sequence

So, to make an object **Iterable** that is to make it work with **for..of** we can:

1 .Make an object an **Iterable** by assigning to it’s mystical **@@iterator**      property through the **Symbol.iterator** property.Here is how:

```
let tempObj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

tempObj[Symbol.iterator]= () => ({
next: function next () {
return {
    done: Object.keys(this).length === 0,
    value: Object.keys(this).shift()
     }
    }
  })

for(key in tempObj){
 console.log(key)
}
// a
// b
// c
```

2.Use **Object.entries**, which returns an **Iterable**:

```
let tempObj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(tempObj)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
// a 1
// b 2
// c 3
```

3.Use **Object.keys**, here is how:

```
let tempObj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
for (let key of Object.keys(tempObj)) {
    console.log(key);
}

// a
// b
// c
```

Hope this helps!!!!!!

Answer (score 12):

Because object literal does not have the [Symbol.iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol) property. To be specific, you can only iterate over [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)(not widely support) and  [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) with [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

To deal with Object Literal iteration, you have two options.

#### for...in

```
for(let key in obj){
    console.log(obj[key]); 
}
```

#### Object.keys + forEach

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    console.log(obj[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is No. It's not possible to use For..Of with Object literals.

I agree with Overv that For..Of is only for iterables. 
I had exactly the same question because I use Objects to iterate over keys and values with for..in. But I just realized that that's what ES6 [MAPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [SETS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) are for.

```
let test = new Map();
test.set('first', "one");
test.set('second', "two");

for(var item of test) {
  console.log(item); // "one" "two"
}
```

Hence it achieves the goal of not having to use for..In (validating with **hasOwnProperty**) and not having to use Object.keys().

Additionally, your keys aren't limited to strings. You can use numbers, objects, or other literals.

Answer (score 2):

Object literals don't have built-in iterators, which are required to work with `for...of` loops.  However, if you don't want to go thru the trouble of adding your own `[Symbol.iterator]` to your object, you can simply use the `Object.keys()` method.  This method returns an `Array` object, which already has a built-in iterator, so you can use it with a `for...of` loop like this:

```
const myObject = {
    country: "Canada",
    province: "Quebec",
    city: "Montreal"
}

for (let i of Object.keys(myObject)) {
    console.log("Key:", i, "| Value:", myObject[i]);
}

//Key: country | Value: Canada
//Key: province | Value: Quebec
//Key: city | Value: Montreal
```

Comment: Using keys every time is more trouble than adding an iterator once. Also, Object.keys() is ES5.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define an iterator over any giving object, this way you can put different logic for each object

```
var x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
x[Symbol.iterator] = function* (){
    yield 1;
    yield 'foo';
    yield 'last'
}
```

Then just directly iterate `x`

```
for (let i in x){
    console.log(i);
}
//1
//foo
//last
```

It is possible to do the same thing on the `Object.prototype` object And have a general iterator for all objects

```
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
    for(let key of Object.keys(this)) {
         yield key 
    } 
 }
```

then iterate your object like this

```
var t = {a :'foo', b : 'bar'}
for(let i of t){
    console.log(t[i]);
}
```

Or this way

```
var it = t[Symbol.iterator](), p;
while(p = it.next().value){
    console.log(t[p])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did the following to easily console out my stuff.

```
for (let key in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key){
    console.log(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of keys? And then [forEach on the Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)?

```
obj = { a: 1, b:2}
Object.keys(obj).forEach( key => console.log(`${key} => ${obj[key]}`))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Array Destruction you can iterate it as follows using `forEach`

```
const obj = { a: 5, b: 7, c: 9 };

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`); // "a 5", "b 7", "c 9"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One-Line answer based on [Mozilla doc Generator - Symbol iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) - Add this to your object to make it **iterable**:

```js
*[Symbol.iterator]() { yield* Object.values(this) }
```

example 1 - getting values:

```js
const person = {
  name: "SeyyedKhandon",
  age: 31,
  *[Symbol.iterator]() { yield* Object.values(this) }
}

// Now you can use "for of"
for (let value of person) {
    console.log(value);    
}
// and also you "spread it"
console.log([...person])
```

example 2 - getting **key-values** using `*[Symbol.iterator]() { yield* Object.entries(this) }`:

```js
const person = {
  name: "SeyyedKhandon",
  age: 31,
  *[Symbol.iterator]() { yield* Object.entries(this) }
}

// for of
for (let item of person) {
    console.log("key:",item[0]," -> ", "value:",item[1]); 
}
// spread it
console.log([...person])
```

Also you can add it later:

```
person[Symbol.iterator]= function*() { yield* Object.entries(person) }
```

```js
const person = {
  name: "SeyyedKhandon",
  age: 31,
}
person[Symbol.iterator]= function*() { yield* Object.entries(person) }

// for of
for (let item of person) {
    console.log("key:",item[0]," -> ", "value:",item[1]); 
}
// spread it
console.log([...person])
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using

```
function* entries(obj) {
    for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        yield [key, obj[key]];
    }
}

for ([key, value] of entries({a: "1", b: "2"})) {
    console.log(key + " " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ES6 you could go with generator:

```
var obj = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'};

function* entries(obj) {
  for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    yield [key, obj[key]];
  }
}

let generator = entries(obj);

let step1 = generator.next();
let step2 = generator.next();
let step3 = generator.next();

console.log(JSON.stringify(step1)); // {"value":["1","a"],"done":false}
console.log(JSON.stringify(step2)); // {"value":["2","b"],"done":false}
console.log(JSON.stringify(step3)); // {"done":true}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/5p3omfeL/1/)
In the output you will get an object with the `"value"` and `"done"` keys. `"Value"` contains everything you *want* it to have and `"done"` is current state of the iteration in bool.

Answer (score 0):

This is from 2015, we are in 2022 and I think we can say that a good way to solve this is adding an iterator.

For example if we had a snippet like this:

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
const [first] = obj
```

It will give us an error that object is not `iterable`

However, it can be iterated using `for ... in`

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
for (const key in obj) {
  console.log('key: ', key)
}
```

#### Teo, how we can make our `obj` instance iterable?

Well it is easy just add the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) like this:

```js
const obj = { a: 'one', b: 'two', c: 'three' }
obj[Symbol.iterator] = () => {
    const entries = Object.entries(obj)
    return {
        next() {
          return {
            done: entries.length === 0,
            value: entries.shift(),
          }
        },
    }
}

const [first] = obj
const [k, v] = first
console.log(`first: [k: ${k}, v:${v}]`)

// Now we can use for of
for (const [k, v] of obj) {
  console.log(`[k:${k}, v:${v}]`)
}
```

This is a very basic implementation you can replace [`Object.entries(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`Object.keys(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [`Object.values(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) according to the needs of  the project.