# How can a Javascript object become iterable with for...of statement?

Tags: javascript, debugging, ecmascript-6, iterator, for-of-loop

I would like to set the `options[Symbol.iterator]` property in order to iterate on the simple objects I create with the `for...of` statement :

```
options = {
  male: 'John',
  female: 'Gina',
  rel: 'Love'
};


for(let p of options){
  console.log(`Property ${p}`);
};
```

But this code gives me the following error:

```
 array.html:72 Uncaught TypeError: options[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
```

How I can set the right iterator function on a simple object as above?

> > Solved

```
 // define the Iterator for the options object 
 options[Symbol.iterator] = function(){

     // get the properties of the object 
     let properties = Object.keys(this);
     let count = 0;
     // set to true when the loop is done 
     isDone = false;

     // define the next method, need for iterator 
     let next = () => {
        // control on last property reach 
        if(count >= properties.length){
           isDone = true;
        }
        return {done:isDone, value: this[properties[count++]]};
     }

     // return the next method used to iterate 
     return {next};
  };
```

And I can use the `for...of` statement on my object now iterable :

```
 for(let property of options){
   console.log(`Properties -> ${property}`);
 }
```

Comment: To use a `for...of` loop, the collection would have to have a `[Symbol.iterator]` property. Object literals do not have such a property, only arrays, Sets, maps etc do

Comment: You want to use a `Map` for that.

Answer (score 32):

To use `for...of` loop you should define an appropriate iterator for your object using `[Symbol.iterator]` key.

Here is one possible implementation:

```js
let options = {
  male: 'John',
  female: 'Gina',
  rel: 'Love',
  [Symbol.iterator]: function * () {
    for (let key in this) {
      yield [key, this[key]] // yield [key, value] pair
    }
  }
}
```

Though, in most cases it'll be better to iterate over objects using plain `for...in` loop instead.

Alternatively you could convert your object to iterable array using `Object.keys`, `Object.values` or `Object.entries` (ES7).

Comment: You really should just do `[Symbol.iterator]() { return Object.entries(this) }` (apart from the fact that there is no `Object.entries` in ES6)

Comment: @Bergi no, it won't work. You have to return an iterator, not an iterable Object. To re-use iterator from `Object.entries` you should `return Object.entries(this)[Symbol.iterator]()`.

Comment: Ouch, I totally forgot that `Object.entries` is a ES7 draft and not a part of ES6.

Comment: Doesn't `entries` already return an iterator? But maybe I'm wrong, or there are multiple drafts.

Comment: @Bergi noop, [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns a plain JS array of `[key, value]` pairs.

Comment: It should only return `this[key]`. from spec: `for (variable of iterable) {statement}` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: This is the way I implemented it: `for (let value of Object.values(this)) yield value`

Answer (score 13):

If you dont want to use generator syntax, you can use another way define iterator function.

```
    var options = {
        male: 'John',
        female: 'Gina',
        rel: 'Love',
        [Symbol.iterator]: function () {
            var self = this;
            var values = Object.keys(this);
            var i = 0;
            return {
                next: function () {
                    return {
                        value: self[values[i++]],
                        done: i >= values.length
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    for (var p of options) {
        console.log(`Property ${p}`);
    }
```

Comment: I like this answer because unlike the generator method, this option allows you to return an object with whatever keys you want (as oppossed to just returning 'value' and 'done') For instance, you could return an object with 'key':values[i++].

Answer (score 6):

Plain objects (`options` in this case) are not iterable in ES6. You need to either define an iterator for your object or do something like:

```
for(let k of Object.keys(options)) {
  console.log(`Property ${k}, ${options[k]}`);
};
```

Comment: There is no `Object.entries` in ES6

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for that! Glad to know that they are bring it back in ES7.

Comment: @hallucinations: They are not going to be part of ES7 either. Most likely ES8.

Comment: @FelixKling I saw [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries) and thought they were!