# Javascript "for..of" not working as expected.

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I seem to be misunderstanding the function of the "for..of" loop. In the example below I am finding the largest sub-array in an Array (in this case [2,-1,7]). When I use the "for..of" loop it returns "NaN", but both a regular for loop "(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)" and the "for..in" return the expected result of 8.

How does "for..of" iterate differently then a regular for loop?

```
var array = [2,-1,7,-7];

var largestSubArray = function (array) {
    var current = 0;
    var newest = 0;

    for(var i of array){
        newest = Math.max(0, newest + array[i]);
        current = Math.max(newest, current);
    }
    return current;
};
console.log(largestSubArray(array));

// Returns NaN, should return 8
```

Comment: You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885220/using-objects-in-for-of-loops

Comment: In `for..of`, `i ` is the value and not key. Try logging `i` in console

Comment: Reading the documentation can be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of ;)

Comment: You should checkout Array.reduce() it's built in and does what you want without you writing a for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Stephen and Andreas. Both read the documentation, and implemented this using reduce before posting but didn't understand the distinction between the two loops. Rob's answer made it click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is not the current index, it is the current value. Try this instead:

```
for(var i of array){
    newest = Math.max(0, newest + i);
    current = Math.max(newest, current);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
newest = Math.max(0, newest + array[i]);
```

to

```
newest = Math.max(0, newest + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up `for...of` with `for...in`. The difference between the two is what is stored in your `i` during iterations. Both differentiate between the `value` and `index` of an array's elements (respectively).

`for...of` sets your `i` to the `value` of the current element in the iteration cycle

`for...in` sets your `i` to the `value` of the current element in the iteration cycle

A simpler way to test this in the future is to `console.log` your variables. A simple test illustrates the above behavior by modifying your code slightly:

```
var array = [2,-1,7,-7];

var largestSubArray = function (array) {
    var current = 0;
    var newest = 0;

    for(var i of array){
        console.log(i, array[i]);
        newest = Math.max(0, newest + array[i]);
        current = Math.max(newest, current);
    }
    return current;
};
console.log(largestSubArray(array));
```

In the above, the result is as follows:

```
i      array[i]
================
2      7
-1     undefined
7      undefined
-7     undefined

NaN
```

This is because `i` is equal to the `value` given the code above. However, changing it from a `for...of` to a `for...in` will yield the following:

```
i      array[i]
================
0      2
1      -1
2      7
3      -7

8
```

Notice your line `newest = Math.max(0, newest + array[i]);`. In your original code, `array[i]` can simply be replaced with `i` when using your `for...of` loop.