# How to sort an array based on Values of it's dynamic Objects

Tags: javascript

This is probably a silly question, but how can I sort the below given array based on Values of it's Objects (Ascending Order - 1 to 6).

I can't use Object Key as an identifier since it's dynamic and will change based on User's settings. I got it working using the commented solution, but it doesn't work in IE since IE doesn't support "Object.values" yet.

```
$scope.data = [            
    { Type: 6 },
    { Path: 1 },
    { Text: 2 },
    { Name: 3 },
    { Icon: 5 },
    { Case: 4 }
];

$scope.data.sort(function (a, b) {
// This commented solution works fine in Chrome and FF, but not in IE since IE doesn't support "Object.values" yet.
//if (Object.values(a) < Object.values(b))
//    return -1;
//if (Object.values(a) > Object.values(b))
//    return 1;
//return 0;

if (a < b)
   return -1;
if (a > b)
   return 1;
return 0;
});

// Desired Result
$scope.data = [
    { Path: 1 },
    { Text: 2 },
    { Name: 3 },
    { Case: 4 },
    { Icon: 5 },
    { Type: 6 }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort by the values of the object.

```js
var data = [{ Type: 6 }, { Path: 1 }, { Text: 2 }, { Name: 3 }, { Icon: 5 }, { Case: 4 }];

data.sort((a, b) => Object.values(a) - Object.values(b));

console.log(data);
```

In IE11 with the first found key of the object.

```js
var data = [{ Type: 6 }, { Path: 1 }, { Text: 2 }, { Name: 3 }, { Icon: 5 }, { Case: 4 }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[Object.keys(a)[0]] - b[Object.keys(b)[0]];
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick asnwer Nina. Your second solution for IE11 fixed the issue. :)

Comment: However, just encountered another error (SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number) in IE11, when I push those objects into that array:

for (column in serverData) {
            var c;
            if (serverData[column] !== 0) {
                c = {[column] : serverData[column]};
                $scope.data.push(c);
            }            
        }

Any idea what could be wrong on this line - " c = {[column] : serverData[column]};" ?

Comment: ie has no computed properties.

Comment: var c = {};
c[column] = serverData[column];

this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to give you the object values in all browsers, including IE.

This answer has a better example than I came up with: [Alternative version for Object.values()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830257/alternative-version-for-object-values/42830295#42830295)