# How to add Object.values pollyfill in IE11 for jquery 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using vue/vuetify, and i'm trying to get it to work in IE11. When I run it, I get this error

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'values'
```

but then when I add a pollyfill

```
    if (!Object.values) {
        Object.prototype.values = function (obj) {
            return Object.keys(obj).map(function (e) {
                return obj[e];
            });
        };
    }
```

I get this from jquery 3.4.0

```
Object.keys: argument is not an Object
```

because it ends up calling the above function, but not passing any params to it. From here

```
    add = function( key, valueOrFunction ) {

        // If value is a function, invoke it and use its return value
        var value = isFunction( valueOrFunction ) ?
            valueOrFunction() :
            valueOrFunction;

        s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" +
            encodeURIComponent( value == null ? "" : value );
    };
```

it calls

```
valueOrFunction() // which is the Object.values()
```

Here is a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cn75e4xs/3/

Open in IE11, and see console tab. I get

```
Object.keys: argument is not an Object
```

because the function gets called without passing a parameter, so `obj` becomes undefined in the pollyfill.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative version for Object.values()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830257/alternative-version-for-object-values)

Comment: Note that while the duplicate's accepted answer uses code similar to yours, there are a number of answers that don't; you should try those.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle. I used the code from the accepted answer, but the problem is jquery is calling it but without passing any params.

Comment: From [jQuery's Browser Support page](https://jquery.com/browser-support/) (which includes IE9+): "Any problem with jQuery in the above browsers should be reported as a bug in jQuery."

Comment: Is the browser running in IE8 mode or something?

Comment: At this point... i'm not confident that this is a jquery problem at all. It appears as though jquery's source does not call Object.values at all.

Comment: Its on IE11. The jsfiddle replicates the issue, if you can run in IE11, and look at console.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on my pollyfill, you will see it gets called, and there is no parameter.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't function at all for me, the two html files 404, and that's it.

Comment: I put a picture on top. It shows that my pollyfill function gets called, and on the right side, it shows it gets called from jquery.

Comment: The fiddle will work, after you click the open in readonly mode, and then page will be white, but you just need to check in console tab. Keep it open before opening the fiddle.

Comment: You are assigning to `Object.prototype.values` for some reason. You should be assigning to `Object.values` instead. Where did you find that polyfill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning to `Object.prototype.values` for some reason. You should be assigning to `Object.values` instead:

```
Object.values = function (obj) {
//    ^ no .prototype
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (e) {
        return obj[e];
    });
};
```

The jQuery code broke because you added a property to `Object.prototype` without [making it non-enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572).